# Entity Framework 6 NotMapped attributes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, fluent, ef-fluent-api

Is there a way using the fluentAPI within a DbContext to manually include ICollections that have been [NotMapped] in the model? I know how to manually ignore properties using the fluentAPI

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Ignore(e => e.MyChildCollection);
```

But if the property was defined with the [NotMapped] attribute (see below), can it be "brought back" into the model?

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual ICollection<ChildEntityType> MyChildCollection { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be. You just have to remove the [NotMapped] Data Annotation and then go to your Package Console Manager. Type add-migration [anyname]. Then type update-database. It will automatically make the changes.

Comment: I'm not actually looking to update the database. We are making all updates to the database directly and not relying upon Entity Framework to update the DB. The way our system is structured, not all models defined for the database tables are referenced by the DLL containing the DbContext objects. We would like all "ICollection" child collections marked as [NotMapped] by default and then explicitly include them in the DbContext model in the "OnModelCreating" override method of the DBContext. I hope that clarifies.